# Can't see text in text boxes using Gnomish Dark theme

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, themes

I am using Xubuntu 14.04.  I just started using it about a week ago.  I am also somewhat new to Linux.  I installed a theme called Gnomish Dark, which I really like, but I have found that on certain websites the text in text boxes can't be seen; it's white on white.  According to the "readme.txt" file that came in Gnomish Dark, the fix for this was to do the following .

**Firefox**

To fix the second issue for Firefox, create `~/.mozilla/firefox/<YOUR_PROFILE>/chrome/userContent.css` with these lines in it:

```
/*------------ start ------------*/
input, textarea, select {
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

a[class="file"],
a[class="dir"],
a[class="symlink"] {
    color: #2EB8E6 !important;
}

a:visited[class="file"],
a:visited[class="dir"],
a:visited[class="symlink"] {
    color: #FF6666 !important;
}
/*------------- end -------------*/
```

I have tried to make the directory `~/.mozilla/firefox/MyName/chrome/userContent.css`, but I keep getting the error: `no such file or directory`.
What am I doing wrong?  I really want to make this theme work.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which command are using to create the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, and then enter the following commands:

`mkdir -p ~/.mozilla/firefox/USERNAME/chrome/`

This will create a the folder(s) that Firefox will look for your .css file in. Then, move to that folder (still in terminal) with

`cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/USERNAME/chrome`

and then create your .css file with

`gedit userContent.css`  which will create a file called userContent.css in the folder you are in and open it for you to start editing.

NOTE: Replace USERNAME with your username.

Comment: Thanks!  I was not putting the -p flag in the command.  I haven't see that before.  Unfortunately, though, it didn't correct my problem as the "readme.txt" file suggested.  Now what?   Hmmm...?  I edited the file and restarted both firefox & the computer, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the next folder:

> $ ls -l ~/.mozilla/firefox/

Between all the folders go to the one that looks like this one and make a folder call chrome:
zynpkipg.default/

> $ mkdir zynpkipg.default/chrome

inside os that folder create a file call "userContent.css" that will contain the css theme. In my case:

> textarea {
>           background-color: white;
>           color: black; }